# Another way to get the instance of the View object in a controller

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I recently moved over from 1.3 to 2.0 of CakePHP. The migration went well, apart from one bit where before I was using the `ClassRegistry::getObject()` method to retrieve the current instance of the View object being used. I was then calling `$view->renderLayout($content, $layout);`. This code was used doing an ajax redirect, and was pretty much the code from [here](http://cakephp.1045679.n5.nabble.com/Redirect-with-ajax-example-td1290159.html).

But now, with CakePHP 2.0 the ability to get the instance of the View object from the [ClassRegistry has been disabled](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html#view-no-longer-registered-in-classregistry), this code no longer works.

So I was wondering if there was another way of getting the same effect but through a different means. I don't really want to do it the javascript way (Manually setting `location.hash`).

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read the source.

```
/**
 * Instance of the View created during rendering. Won't be set until after Controller::render() is called.
 *
 * @var View
 */
    public $View;
```

ClassRegistry was never really thought to be used with other things than models.